# Multiply column values in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am a total noob at ruby on rails so what I am trying to do is multiply the value of each row in two columns together and store it in a new object. I know how I would do it in mysql but when I do something like this in my .erb file

```
@ordertotals = Orderline.where(:id =>  @orderparts.id).sum("quantity * price")
```

I get this error

```
undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x7f843ff72ce8>
```

I have been looking around and cant find an explanation of how to actually do a where search that I understand. I have seen that some things actually need to go in the model file but I dont know where to begin on how to define that in the model or call it passing it the needed info from the .erb file, can anyone explain this to me?

```
class Orderline < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :order
end
```

Comment: the orderline model looks like `class Orderline < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :order
end`

Comment: @user2793027 Can you actually update your question with the body of the Orderline class.  If it's actually an ActiveRecord::Base subclass then it should certainly respond to `where`

Comment: which version of rails are you on? `where` was added only in rails 3. It was not available in 2.3.x or lower.

Comment: I am using v1.8.7 sadly and i cannot update the version :\

Comment: 1.8.7 sounds like your ruby version. Rails 3.2 runs on ruby 1.8.7, this can be set in your Gemfile: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html

Comment: sorry rails version is 2.3.14

Comment: @Eternal-Learner: Excellent guess! You might want to turn that into an answer.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks. Just posted it as an answer.

Comment: You shouldn't be querying your database in your .erb file. Do computations and queries in your controller, not the view.

Answer (score 2):

`where` was added only in Rails 3.x. Since you are on Rails 2.3.x, you have to use the old syntax.

```
@ordertotals = Orderline.find(:all, :conditions => ["id = ?", @orderparts.id], :select => "quantity * price as total_price")
```

I hope I have got the syntax right. Don't have rails 2 to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for Rails 2.3.x

```
@ordertotals = Orderline.all(:conditions=>"id='#{@orderparts.id}'",:select=>"quantity * price as PRODUCT")
```